# Mock FileInputStream in FileReader can't work using PowerMock

Tags: filereader, powermock, fileinputstream, powermockito

I noticed that in FileReader constructor, the FileInputStream is created. So I what to Mock it in the FileReader class, but it can't work. Can anyone figure it out?

The code it like below:

```
package util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FileReader.class, ContentReader.class})
public class FileReaderTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetContent() throws Exception {
        File file = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream("123".getBytes()));
        PowerMockito.whenNew(InputStreamReader.class)
                .withArguments(Mockito.any(FileInputStream.class)).thenReturn(isr);
        Assert.assertEquals("123", ContentReader.getContent(file));
    }

}

class ContentReader {

    public static String getContent(File file) throws IOException {
        String content = "unknown";
        BufferedReader in = null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        content = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        return content;
    }

}
```

Comment: `ContentReader::getContent` is equivalent to `PidHelper::getPidFromFile` ?

Comment: Who does call the `new InputStreamReader`?

Comment: @gontard,Yes. Sorry for that. I have changed the code

Comment: @ArthurZagretdinov, FileReader extends from InputStreamReader, So when the new FileReader(fiel) is called, the new InputStreamReader is called as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shot answer - it's impossible, because to mock system classes the PowerMock should be able to modified a client class which uses system class. In your case both classes: who uses and what is used are system classes. More you can read [here](https://www.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/) (it's about static calls of system classes, but same true for mocking constructor call)

Also, please check this good point: [don't mock what you don't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own). For you it means:

- You should wrap reading data from file via util class which you can mock
- Write an integration test for your util class. If `ContentReader`
  is an util class then you shouldn't write unit test for it.